# SCL01x Contactless Reader with PCSC lite on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, nfc, pcsc

I am having smartcard reader from [Ingenico](http://healthcare-eid.ingenico.com/en/TEO.aspx), trying to make it work on Ubuntu 12.4. 64bit

I have already installed pcsc lite and libusb and reader driver which is
SCL01x Contactless Reader - driver.

The situation is when i plug the rader in my USB port, signal light is off on reader.

**When i try to run pcscd i get his errors:**

```
00000000 dyn_unix.c:37:DYN_LoadLibrary() /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/SCLGENERIC.bundle/Contents/Linux/libSCLGENERIC.so.2.09: /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/SCLGENERIC.bundle/Contents/Linux/libSCLGENERIC.so.2.09: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
00000096 readerfactory.c:996:RFInitializeReader() RFLoadReader failed: 0xFFFFFFFF80100014
00000074 readerfactory.c:312:RFAddReader() SCL011G Contactless Reader [SCL01x Contactless Reader] (21161207200555) init failed.
00000047 hotplug_libudev.c:391:HPAddDevice() Failed adding USB device: SCL011G Contactless Reader
```

**when i run pcsc_scan:**

```
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.18 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.7.4
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: SCL011G Contactless Reader [SCL01x Contactless Reader] (21161207200555) 00 00

Fri Jan 17 03:27:45 2014
Reader 0: SCL011G Contactless Reader [SCL01x Contactless Reader] (21161207200555) 00 00
  Card state:
```

And nothing...

I tried also example with smartcardio package in java, and error is: no terminals, cardreader can not be found.
When i run lsusb, there is my reader in device list marked as SCM Microsystem

***[EDIT][1.0]***
I have managed to start pcscd service, now i can see that device is working by signal lights
When i swipe smart card over it the lights are working.
64bit driver installed

```
Trying to figure out why do i get error: SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.
after pcsc_scan command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
After finding and installing 64bit driver i just killed pcscd service.
I made it like this:

```
sudo killall pcscd
sudo pcscd -fd
```

After that i was able to read smart card with my reader.

Also sample code from java.samrtcardio worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The driver failed to load: `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 00000096`

You are attempting to load a 32 bit library on a 64 bit platform. Either run a 32bit chroot/multilib setup or obtain/compile the library for 64bits

Comment: You may want to back that up with more details, else this maybe deleted.

Comment: Yes it is obvious i have loaded 32 bit library.
Can you give me more details how to run a 32bit chroot/multilib setup? There is no 64bit driver for this device as i can see.
EDIT
I have run sudo service pcscd start
and i can see that device is working, signal lights are blinking when i swipe nfc card over it.
When i go with pcsc_scan i get this:
SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.

Comment: I found 64 bit driver, installed, when i run pcsc_scan i always get error:
SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.
How can I start that service? pcscd deamon is running as i can see.